# CakePHP 2 cannot connection with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to set up CakePHP 2 in my virtually owned server. The only step missing is connecting MySQL. I've edited my database.php file to include the following.

```
'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'database' => 'paulncks_money',
    'host' => 'server189.web-hosting.com',
    'login' => 'paulncks_teller',
    'password' => '**********',
```

However, cake php gives me this error

```
Error: A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.    

The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

I've migrated my database onto the server and tried every possible hostname.

**One possible fix**

I tried being more specific and included the port on my hostname.

```
'host' => 'server189.web-hosting.com',
```

This change returned a new set of errors. I don't know if I am any closer to solving my problem, but these errors are so bizzare.

```
Warning (2): Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 80. Packet 
size=5526600 [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 184]
Warning (2): PDO::__construct() [<a 
href='http://php.net/pdo.construct'>pdo.construct</a>]: MySQL server has 
gone away [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 184]
Warning (2): PDO::__construct() [<a 
href='http://php.net/pdo.construct'>pdo.construct</a>]: Error while reading 
greeting packet. PID=294504 [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, 
line 184]
```

Am I closer to connecting?

Comment: Please note `$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); ` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be i'm too late but this can help some one else

Possible reasons for [SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006]](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-2013-01-02/)

The most common of them is (point 4 from the link) :

> max_allowed_packet = 1M

Try to increase to 4M, 8M or 16M (to do that you need access to mysql config file)

One advice don't show mysql server settings (host, login and so on)

Comment: Thank you, I increased the memory limit but it still did not work. However, I was able to fix my problem by making sure that my user/pass actually existed in mysql. I did this using ssh puTTY.

Comment: Also make sure that your mySql user has access to the database you want to connect it to.